# How to Implement Page Navigation in Astro about dynamic route (same vue-router)?

Tags: routes, astrojs

I am working on a website using Astro and looking to implement navigation from a list page (`listPage`) to a detail page (`idPage`). Specifically, on the `listPage`, I have a series of product cards fetched from an API, each card should include a link that, when clicked, navigates to the `idPage` that displays detailed information about that product.

For example, when a user clicks on a product card on the `/list` page, they should be navigated to the `/products/[id]` page, where `[id]` is the unique identifier of the product.

#### My current challenges are:

1. How to set up this kind of routing from the list page to the detail page in Astro?
2. How should I organize my file structure to support dynamic routing?
3. Are there any best practices recommended for implementing this functionality?

I am somewhat confused about how to effectively achieve this functionality in Astro and hope to get some advice and guidance from the community. Thank you very much!

Comment: see https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/routing/ Please be more specific if you have a problem/issue that's not answered there.